# Graphing the result of a non-linear regression on a scatter plot

Tags: r, plot, regression

I've been attempting to draw the non-parametric part of a regression on a scatter plot, with confidence intervals if possible. Even if I tried, I failed, reason why I'm asking here

```
library(np)
library(foreign)  

wage1 <- read.dta(file="PATH HERE\\wage1.dta")
reg.np <- npplreg(lwage ~ female + married + educ + tenure | exper, data = wage1)

plot(reg.np)

plot(wage1$exper, wage1$lwage, xlab = "age", ylab = "log(wage)")
lines(wage1$exper, fitted(reg.np), lty = 1, col = "blue")
```

This was one of the many attempts I tried. I'd really appreciate if someone could help.

wage1 Database: http://www.sendspace.com/file/txksv3

Answer (score 1):

I can't access the wage1 data, but I think what you want to do to create a new data frame that contains appropriate x-axis values, and use this as an argument to predict() to get appropriate y-axis values.  Use these x and y-axis values to add the model to your plot.

If you want to use fitted(), you might need to sort the data in increasing order of the x variate.